# Why is my code resizing fine in the browser and at android phones, but do apple devices not listen to my media queries?

Tags: css, iphone, resize, media

So i've been working on my website and trying to get it to resize correctly. The text was proving difficult so I had to make a couple of media queries to make it work on whatever size screen. It works fine on android, on my laptop and on those sites where you can see the different screen sizes. However on iphones? It doesn't work as it should (but it doesn't seem to ignore it completely, it just doesn't totally make the media queries work as they should?)
I have the viewport tag so that's not the problem. I didn't make my queries exact screen sizes but more so tried to make the text look okay when I thought it started to look weird (which in hindsight probably not the best plan but hey, im still learning how to code).

So i'm wondering where it goes wrong?
(www.ellistolsma.nl is the site).

Already tried the viewport tag, changing the positions of the meta tags, changing max-width to max-device-width, changing screen sizes, tried different browsers.

These are my queries:

```
   @media (min-width: 536px) and (max-width: 900px) { some irrelevant code I think }

   @media (min-width: 370px) and (max-width: 536px) { }

   @media (min-width: 250px) and (max-width: 370px) { }

   @media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 250px) { }



 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="eng">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0" />
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>Ellis Tolsma</title>

</head>
```

Comment: Could you provide more detailed CSS code and explain what you are expecting to happen?